# Error rendering MIME Types of assets in Golang server

Tags: templates, go, server, mime-types, mime

I've got a basic Go server rendering a single page. However, when the page loads, it can't retrieve static assets (style.css, app.js) because they keep being rendered with MIME type 'text/html' instead of their respective types.

I get this error when I load the page:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/style.css"

I know the issue has to do with the HTTP Headers and setting the appropriate Content-Type. However, I'm not sure how to do that for assets that the page itself retrieves. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, msg *Message, path string) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(path)
    if err != nil {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
    }
    // problem is here I think
    err = t.Execute(w, msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error writing to response writer\n\b", err)
    }
    return
 }

func mainHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, r, &Message{Title: "What the Fuck is Open?", Text: "Would you like to sort by prominence or distance?"}, HOME)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create an assetsHandler to deal with static assets requests.

```
// if you are using grilla/mux
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/static/"+`{path:\S+}`, AssetsHandler)
```

add `Content-Type Header` based on assets' suffix:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/css")
```

`.css` -> `text/css`

`.js` -> `text/javascript`

...

Comment: How do I handle the asset requests? Not sure how to route that.

Comment: add an example to my answer.

Comment: What does `{ path:\S+}` means? It looks like a regex but how does it work with gorilla mux?